# Getting a 404 on google's official endpoint for access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm getting a 404 each time I try to access this endpoint
`https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`

Don't know why, it was working just a few weeks before

I have tried with another IP and in multiple browsers, it is supposed to work as in the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to exchange an authorization code for a token, you need to make a `POST` request to the https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token endpoint as described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#exchange-authorization-code). If you make a `GET` request to the same URL, you will receive a `404` error response.

The following snippet from the documentation shows a sample request:

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth2.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
client_id=your_client_id&
client_secret=your_client_secret&
redirect_uri=https%3A//oauth2.example.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

Here is an example of a `curl` command that attempts to do a `GET` request on that url, receiving a `404` response:

```
% curl -D - https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
HTTP/2 404 
content-type: text/html
date: Wed, 26 Apr 2023 17:31:58 GMT
server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
content-length: 0
x-xss-protection: 0
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
```

By changing the request to a `POST`, the error changes from a `404` (Not found) to a `400` (Bad request), due to the missing `grant_type`.

```
% curl -D - -d '{}' https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
HTTP/2 400 
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
vary: X-Origin
vary: Referer
vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
date: Wed, 26 Apr 2023 17:42:16 GMT
server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
cache-control: private
x-xss-protection: 0
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
accept-ranges: none

{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "
}%
```